# ssh process started by default

Tags: 12.04

As soon as log into the system, I can see the following ssh processes.

```
root      1899     1  0 12:35 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/.sshdd1407654346
root      1904  1899  0 12:35 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/.sshdd1407654346
root      1905  1904  0 12:35 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/.sshdd1407654346
root      1907  1904  0 12:35 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/.sshdd1407654346
root      1909  1904  0 12:35 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/.sshdd1407654346
```

Is this some sort of virus? How to get rid of it ?

As soon as I login to the system as a normal user and do 'ps -ef | grep ssh', I get the above output. As you can see, the process 1899 is started by 'init' (PID = 1). I tried to kill these processes using the root login but they just start again.

Comment: That is indeed odd, in general I wouldn't expect any process to be running from `/tmp`. Have you installed any additional ssh packages? Have you installed anything to do with a Solid State Hard Drive? Also please post the output of `ls -alph /tmp/.sshdd1407654346`. Finally, see if you can open the file in a text editor and see what's inside.

Comment: Are you ssh-ing in as root?

Comment: I have not installed any additional ssh packages nor have installed anything to do with SSD (since I do no have one). As soon as I login to the system as a normal user and do 'ps -ef | grep ssh', I get the above output. As you can see, the process 1899 is started by 'init' (PID = 1). I tried to kill these processes using the root login but they just start again. Any help to get rid of them would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system is hacked. There are numerous ways and tools to detect and fix that, try to start with something like chkrootkit, http://www.chkrootkit.org/

More information on this topic:

https://serverfault.com/questions/208782/my-linux-server-was-hacked-how-do-i-find-out-how-and-when-it-was-done

https://serverfault.com/questions/650/how-can-i-detect-unwanted-intrusions-on-my-servers

http://garryjbs.hubpages.com/hub/Few-signs-that-your-Linux-server-has-been-hacked